# Why does my browser display abnormally few special characters?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, special-characters

[image]

I want to insert some special characters in Google Docs. However,there are many that my browser doesn't seem to recognize. How can I get my browser to recognize them?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons: 1) your computer does not have any font containing those characters, so your browsers displays a small rectangle; 2) there is, but your browser does not find it, with the same result—this happens especially with IE, but also with other browsers.

In case 1, it suffices to download and install a suitable font. This depends on the characters you are interested, and to some extent on the platform. For example, to get the mathematical bold letters that are missing in the picture, you could use [FreeSerif](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/).

Case 2 might be trickier, but fortunately it is getting rare. Google Docs use a `font-family` value of `arial, sans-serif`, so browsers will primarily look at Arial, then the system’s default sans-serif font. This is a bit unfortunate here, since sans-serif fonts are generally unsuitable for mathematical expressions. And I am afraid [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d400/fontsupport.htm) to the mathematical bold letters does not include sans-serif fonts, though there might be some special fonts for the purpose. So my advice would be that instead of trying to make a misbehaving browser use a suitable font, you try some other browser that can utilize different fonts in the system.